# Google OAuth CredentialDataStore and Server Clustering

Tags: java, oauth, google-oauth, credentials

I have this code

```
        AuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                new NetHttpTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), 
                clientSecrets, 
                loadScopes())
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .setCredentialDataStore(StoredCredential.getDefaultDataStore(new FileDataStoreFactory(new File("/dir/datastoredir"))))
```

When a google user authorizes my web application to access some of his data, I can correctly access his data through the Google API.
Very good.

The problem is that this "credential" is stored locally **only** on the application server that physically managed that request (in its directory "/dir/datastoredir")

If I have a clustered job that for examples read and synchs the users Google Calendars with my application, probably that job will not run on the application server that managed the OAUTH authorization from the user. (a similar problem might happen to the user is he browse my website and the loadbalancer redirects him to a different application server node)

**First question**: am I doing right? Is it "normal" that a Application Server that has no access to the "/dir/datastoredir" of the first application server that managed the OAUTH process, has not the rights to read the user data from Google API?

**Second question**: how workaround this problem? For security reason the only communication channel open from my application servers is to the Database. (I can't setup network shared filesystem directories...)
From my architectural point of view, those credentials received after a OAUTH process should be centrally stored in the DB.

From what I've read the only way to do this is through JDO, but i'm not using JDO in my application. I'm using JPA (or sometimes I use plain JDBC).
It seems quite weird to me that there is not a default implementation to have those OAUTH credentials managed centrally in a database through JDBC or JPA..